# How to make Appbar up button back to previous Fragment instead back to Home Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-manifest

First of all, I'll give my package structure:

```
├── Home Activity
│   ├── Menus Activity
│   │   ├── Menus Fragment
│   │   ├── Web View Fragment
```

And there is my **Manifest code of my Menus Activity**:

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".views.menus.MenusActivity"
    android:exported="false"
    android:parentActivityName=".views.home.HomeActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.lib_name"
        android:value="" />
</activity>
```

I set HomeActivity as a parent activity of my MenusActivity. And implement `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` and `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)` into my MenusActivity. Its work properly, when we press the up button, we'll be redirected back to HomeActivity.

But there's the problem, All of my MenusActivity logical business is goes to MenusFragment. And when an item is got clicked on that Fragment layout. It'll replace the MenusFragment layout to WebViewFragment layout. And when I wanna return back to MenusFragment layout, by clicking the Up Button, it doesn't direct me to MenusFragment, instead back to HomeActivity.

I has implement `addToBackStack(null)` into my WebViewFragment, but its only work on device soft back button, and not affecting the appbar up button.

How to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MenusActivity override the `onOptionsItemSelected method to handle the Up button as below

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if (item.itemId == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed() // Handle Up button click by calling onBackPressed()
        return true
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

When you calling WebViewFragment fragment from MenusFragment make `addToBackStack(null)` as below

```
val webViewFragment = WebViewFragment()
val transaction = fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
transaction?.replace(R.id.fragment_container, webViewFragment)
transaction?.addToBackStack(null) // Add WebViewFragment to the back stack
transaction?.commit()
```

In your WebViewFragment, handle the back button click to navigate as below

```
val backButton = rootView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.back_button)
backButton.setOnClickListener {
    activity?.onBackPressed() // Navigate back to the previous fragment
}
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Can't resolve R.id.back_button

Comment: Any view relevant to that id?

Comment: this is the back action view id from your WebviewFragment. you can change it as per your requirements

Comment: Ohh thank you sir, its work! I change `R.id.back_button` to `R.id.home` but we should to define it on `onAttach()` or `onCreateView()` method, because if we define it on `onViewCreated()` method, it will raise `NullPointerException` because we trying to add View$OnClickListener to null reference object.